# Manual string split in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

In my code, I am attempting to manipulate a string:

```
Some text - 04.09.1996 - 40-18
```

I'd like to split this into three substrings: `Some text`, `04.09.1996`, and `40-18`.

When I use the `Split` method with a hyphen as a separator, the return value is an array of four strings: `Some text`, `04.09.1996`, `40`, and `18`. How can I make this code work as described above?

Comment: Can `Some text` include " - " in it?  For instance, can your input string look like this `ABC - DEF - 04.09.1996 - 40-18`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should just split with spaces around `-`:

```
 .Split(new[] {" - "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

See [C# demo](https://ideone.com/4sgoaT)

```
var res = "Some text - 04.09.1996 - 40-18".Split(new[] {" - "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var s in res)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Result:

```
Some text
04.09.1996
40-18
```

Comment: Is `RemoveEmptyEntries` really important here?

Comment: @Rawling: You can use `StringSplitOptions.None` if you need empty values, too. Judging by the current task, `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` should be OK. If you wonder if there is a `string.Split` overload with only 1 argument, [no, all the overloads allowing a string require the `StringSplitOptions` argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 16):

Use [this overload of string split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda(v=vs.110).aspx) to only get 3 parts:

```
var s = "Some text - 04.09.1996 - 40-18";
var parts = s.Split(new[] { '-' }, 3);
```

I'm assuming you also want to trim the spaces too:

```
var parts = s.Split(new[] { '-' }, 3)
    .Select(p => p.Trim());
```

Comment: The second option here is the only answer that works correctly if the formatting is not fixed, i.e. if the number of spaces around the hyphens can vary.

Answer (score 3):

I would be wary of "-" or " - " appearing in "Some text", as I assume that you are interested in that as a place holder.  If you are certain that "Some text" will not contain "-" than the other answers here are good, simple and readable.  Otherwise we need to rely on something that we know is constant about the string. It looks to me like the thing that is constant is the last 3 hyphens.  So I would try split on "-" and put the last pair back together like

```
string input = "Some text - 04.09.1996 - 40-18";
string[] foo = input.Split(new[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int length = foo.Length;
string[] bar = new string[3];

//put "some text" back together
for(int i=0; i< length - 3;i++)
{
   bar[0] += foo[i];
}

bar[1] = foo[length - 3];
bar[2] = foo[length - 2] + "-" + foo[length - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

In current case you can use Split with extra space like

```
string.Split(" - ")
```

In term of "good practice" can't recommend this solution.

Comment: Please use code formatting, not quoting for code blocks.

Comment: Thanks DavidG, will do

Comment: Also as a general rule, if your answer is the same as someone else's, don't post, but upvote the other answer :)
If you have somethign to add, a comment or edit suggestion is always welcome

Comment: I would love to know why this is not considered good practice, and what would make it better.

Comment: Is not a good practice because split by "blank" spaces is very dogie. As you can see, in example above you can have "34-35" or "text - " and many others examples. In this case, this solution works, in others it wont, and after a while, when problem occurs, is hard to find the problem. So, I'd say, the optimal solution is in above example, where you remove spaces and split string only in 3 parts. 
P.S. I wrote my solution in same time with guys above.

Comment: This code doesn't compile.  You need to pass the string as an array.

Comment: I assume you mean "string" doesn't compile because is a key word, just rename your variable. I just meant like "any string"

Comment: @DenisBaciu, no, the argument in Split is the one causing it not to compile. You need to pass either a char, or a string array. See the other answers for how they're doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I am replaced character sequence '--------------------' in your string to special character "&" like below.  and then split using special character "&"

```
 string str = "Hello, my- name --------------------  is Philip J. Fry -------------------- and i like cartoons".Replace("--------------------","&");
  string[] ss=str.Split('&');
  string result=ss[0] + "," + ss[1]+ "," +ss[2];
```

then output string looks like  "Hello, my- name, is Philip J. Fry, and i like cartoons"

Comment: Does this answer the question?